# Matrix issues using with Solspace Importer

Tags: matrix, solspace, pixelandtonic, solspace-importer

I'm using Solspace Importer to import data from a JSON data feed, and all is working well. As Grid isn't currently supported, I'm using Matrix for my repeatable entries.

All works well on initial run, but on next run of the import, the following errors are thrown.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'is_draft'
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2409

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal string offset 'is_draft'
Filename: matrix/ft.matrix.php
Line Number: 2461
```

Not really sure why this is failing the second time around, but maybe something to do with updating entries incorrectly?

Let me know if any more info is required!

Comment: What version of EE, Importer and Matrix are you using? Are you also using Better Workflow (I forget if Matrix's `is_draft` is there for BWF). Could you also show us what the JSON file looks like? A simple working example, that still causes the error, would do.

Comment: Using Matrix 2.6.1, Importer 2.2.5, EE 2.9.2. Not using Better Workflow. Notably, commenting out lines 2409, 2461 in ft.matrix.php means it works just fine. Will update with sample JSON.

Comment: Encountering the same issue. No BWF. Tried upgrading matrix to 2.6.1. Importer 2.2.5. EE v2.6.1